# Why are the events set up in Google Tag Manager not being tracked in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I think I'm experiencing a bug linking my GTag and Analytics account.

In my Google Tag account I have the following event set up:

[image]

[image]

As you can see every time there is a page visited that contains `VisaSupport` on my site, it's supposed to fire an event into Google Analytics.

However, when I'm on the Realtime tab of my GA account I can't see any events fired when I open that page.

I also don't have them historically tracked.

Is there a possibility that the two accounts are not linked right?

I did check the Variables in Google Tags and the Analytics account is linked to the correct ID.

Thanks!

PS the page in question to test is https://waytorussia.net/Travel/VisaSupport.html

Comment: Non-interaction hits dont show up in Real time reporting. However im not seeing any events apart from the pageview firing when I checked the page. While testing change the non-interaction hit to false, also in the event tag override the GA settings and put the GA tracking id in manually. I would also change the trigger to Pageview - Dom Ready with Page URL contains VisaSupport (incase there is some issue there with the pageview and event both firing together)

Comment: Also did you publish the container (or at least refresh the container after making the changes) so you can see what is being fired via the gtm debugging frame when in preview mode

Comment: @BronwynV your answer was correct! Maybe you want to post it as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Did you publish the container (or at least refresh the container after making the changes) so you can see what is being fired via the gtm debugging frame when in preview mode?

Non-interaction hits don't show up in Real time reporting.
However im not seeing any events apart from the pageview firing when I checked the page.

While testing change the non-interaction hit to false, also in the event tag override the GA settings and put the GA tracking id in manually. I would also change the trigger to Pageview - Dom Ready with Page URL contains VisaSupport (incase there is some issue there with the pageview and event both firing together)